# write a HyperLink code in aspx from code behind

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, code-behind

how can i write this code from aspx page in code behind?

```
<a href="skype:MySkype?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons  /buttons/call_blue_white_124x52.png" style="border: none;" width="124" height="52" alt="Skype Me™!" /></a>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `PlaceHolder` control in the Page where you want this to appear.

Then write

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<a href=\"skype:MySkype?call\"><img src=\"http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_white_124x52.png\" style=\"border: none;\" width=\"124\" height=\"52\" alt=\"Skype Me™!\" /></a>"));
```

Hopes you are using C#

**Edit**
If you are looking to add dynamically, then place the above place holder and then use below.

```
HyperLink hyp=new HyperLink();
hyp.ID="hyp1";
hyp.ImageUrl="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_white_124x52.png";
hyp.NavigateUrl="skype:MySkype?call";
hyp.Text="Skype Me™!" ;
hyp.ToolTip="Skype Me™!";
hyp.Target="_new";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(hyp);
```

Comment: thanks be this did not work is there a way doing this dynamically like HyperLink hyperLink = new HyperLink();     ant then add to the href the string and the image to the hyperLink ?

Comment: Two things: you've actually created two separate links in your answer, and why does he need a placeholder in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

if you're going to create a DataTable for GridView and add all column names and datas from codebehind and need to rearrange some of columns (like adding hyperlinks or etc.) i think this might be useful.

for my situation i need to rearrange my rows' cells like that (currently i have 6 cells, and want to change 6. value)

in gridview's RowDataBound event

```
string myVariable = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;//i'm getting value from index number 0
HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
hp.NavigateUrl = String.Format("some_aspx_page.aspx?myVariable={0}", myVariable);
hp.Text = "Link name";
e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(hp); //and add to index number 5
```